# Algorithm that returns false If the result has already come out before in R

Tags: r, algorithm, loops

I want to make an algorithm that returns false If the result has already come out before.
Below i attach the code i'm using, but it seems not to be the correct one.
I'll be appreciate any help.

```
x1 <- c("LMP","Dp","LMP","LMP","Dp")
x2 <- c("Dp","Dp","LMP","LMP","Dp")


for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(i==1){TRUE}else{
      if(length(unique(x[1:i]))==1){FALSE}else{TRUE}}}
# The result that i want is 
# for x1:

TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
# for x2:

TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `duplicated` instead of a `for` loop - `duplicated` returns `TRUE` for each duplicate element, by negating (`!`), TRUE -> FALSE, and viceversa.

```
!duplicated(x1)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
!duplicated(x2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

It can be done in a `for` loop as well.

```
f1 <- function(vec) {

  un1 <- ""
  out <- logical(length(vec))
  for(i in seq_along(vec)) {
    if(!vec[i] %in% un1) {
       un1 <- c(un1, vec[i])
       out[i] <- TRUE
    }

   }
  out

}
```

-testing

```
> f1(x1)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> f1(x2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! it's what i looking for!!